# Complex SQL query Help Pls

Tags: sql

Well I have 2 Table named 'A' and 'B'

One of the tables(A) include many records in this records ı have a column holding 'SENDER_CONTACT_NUMBER' it can be too many invoice from same sender.

Other table Holding 'SENDER_CONTACT_NUMBER' and 'STATUS'(1 - is active )( 0 - is not active) so in this table 'SENDER_CONTACT_NUMBER' is unique and I want make sql query that  Union 2 tables 'SENDER_CONTACT_NUMBER' and I want to create 2. column for each 'SENDER_CONTACT_NUMBER' And I want to take Counts in table A (I solve the first part but second is real problem to me cause B table 'SENDER_CONTACT_NUMBER' may not be in A table so in this case I couldn't show counts :(

TABLE A

```
INVOICE_TYPE_CODE   varchar no
SENDER_CONTACT_NUMBER   varchar no
SENDER_IDENTIFIER   varchar no
SENDER_NAME         varchar no
RECEIVER_CONTACT    varchar no
RECEIVER_IDENTIFIER varchar no
RECEIVER_NAME           varchar no
```

TABLE B

```
SENDER_CONTACT_NUMBER   varchar no
URUN            varchar no
BASTAR             char no
BITTAR             char no
STATUS         smallint no
```

Result that I want to see

COLUMN 1

Union SENDER_CONTACT_NUMBER LIST BY STATUS=1

COLUMN 2

For each record in sender_contact_number at column 1 show counts in a if there is no record put 0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUpQu.jpg)

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the question. Do you want a list of SENDER_CONTACT_NUMBER with status=1 and for each of these active senders, the number of elements in table A?

Comment: It would be useful to post the query that you have so far that gives you some of the count values that you want. It could be as simple as using a `LEFT JOIN` on the tables to get what you want. You may either be using the wrong type of join, or only referencing table A when you need both.

Comment: @RobertKock well ı want to union that A and B(Status Active) than ı want to number of elements at A

Comment: Still not very clear but I guess @cf_en already answered your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want a count of the number of occurrences of each `SENDER_CONTACT_NUMBER` in table A, including records from B that have no corresponding record in A, then this should work:

```
SELECT B.SENDER_CONTACT_NUMER, COUNT(A.INVOICE_TYPE_CODE) AS Invoices
FROM B
    LEFT JOIN A ON B.SENDER_CONTACT_NUMER = A.SENDER_CONTACT_NUMER
WHERE B.STATUS = 1  -- Only include active contacts
```

Comment: Not like this ı already tried   SELECT DISTINCT mu.SENDER_CONTACT_NUMBER   AS unionVkn FROM Bmu where  mu.STATUS=1 UNION SELECT DISTINCT ot.SENDER_CONTACT_NUMBER   AS unionVkn FROM Aot  as union now ı need to take number of elemets at A for VknList

Comment: Why not like this? I don't really understand why you've written your query as a `UNION`. What it is doing is getting all of the active `SENDER_CONTACT_NUMBER` from B, and each distinct `SENDER_CONTACT_NUMBER` from A, and performing the `UNION`. The UNION function will eliminate duplicates, so all your query is doing is giving you the values from B, plus any that are in A that are not in B.

Comment: Your query over-complicates getting the set of `SENDER_CONTACT_NUMBER` that you want to count. Did you try the query I provided?